# counting quicksort comparisons

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I implemented a simple quick sort (code below) to count the average and worst comparison made by quicksort. I declared a global variable to hold the counter for comparisons. I placed 3 counters in different positions that I thought would count the comparisons, the problem is the counter sum does not match the theoretical value of the total number of comparisons made by quick sort. I tried to solve this problem for hours but came up short. I really appreciate if you can point me where I should put the counters and why I should place them there. I assumed a counter should go where ever a comparison is made. apparently I'm wrong.

```
public int[] quickSort(int[] array, int start, int end){


    if (start < end){
        counter++;//1st comparison here
        int pivot;  

        pivot = Partition(array, start, end);
        quickSort(array, start, pivot - 1);
        quickSort(array, pivot + 1, end );
    }
return  array;
}

private int Partition(int[] array, int start, int end) {
    int pivot = array[end];
    int i = start - 1;

    for(int j = start; j <= end - 1; j++){

        counter++;//2nd comparison here


        if (array[j] <= pivot){
            counter++;//3rd comparison here
            i = i + 1;

            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }

    }

    int temp = array[i+1];
    array[i+1] = array[end];
    array[end] = temp;

    return i + 1;
}
```

Comment: How does the first call to `quicksort` look like? You can also post some examples of what is the theoretical and actual number of comparisons.

Comment: im choosing the last element to be the pivot on purpose. I tried leaving only the third counter, but my counter is larger by almost 25 percent, im calculating the theoretical value to be SIZE * (SIZE-1)/2 where SIZE is the array size for the worst case. the first call looks like quickSort(testArray, 0, testArray.length - 1)

Comment: for a 1000 randomly generated numbers stored in an array, the expected value is around 499500

Comment: What data are you using? If you sorted [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], that will give you more comparisons that [1, 8, 9, 5, 4, 2, 3, 6, 0]. Are you trying to get a maximal theoretical comparisons or the actual ones?

Comment: @JakubZaverka by leaving out only the third comparison, It worked. Thank you.yes I was trying to get maximal theoretical comparisons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the theory, only the comparisons of array elements are counted, not the comparisons of indices to the bounds, so you should only leave the second `counter++;` (you need to increment the counter independently of the result of the comparison).

Then there is the question against which theoretical values you compare. There are different implementations of quicksort which use slightly different numbers of comparisons. In particular, your choice of the pivot makes no attempt to avoid extreme values, so this implementation will easily degrade to O(n^2) behaviour.

Comment: Yes im doing that on purpose, choosing the last element to be the pivot. I tried leaving only the third counter, but my counter is larger by almost 25 percent, im calculating the theoretical value to be SIZE * (SIZE-1)/2 where SIZE is the array size for the worst case.

Comment: Oops, should be the second, not the third, see edit. So in the loop, you make `end-start` comparisons. That generates at most `SIZE*(SIZE-1)/2` comparisons in total, as you expect. If you get different results after taking out the other `counter++;`, I don't see how that could happen, must investigate.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: +1 but...  Aren't most QuickSort implementation starting with a *shuffle* as to make worst case behavior much less likely, regardless of the way the pivot is chosen?

Comment: @TacticalCoder Not that I know of. As far as I know most implementations ensure O(n*log n) behaviour by choosing the pivot so that it's guaranteed to split the array not too unevenly, or by falling back to heapsort, mergesort or another O(n*log n) sort when they recur too deeply. But I'm not a sorting expert, so shuffling may be common despite me not having heard of it.