# Counting data comparisons for Java quick sort

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to count the number of data comparisons in this quick sort algorithm, but am surely incrementing too often as my expected output is much lower than what I am currently getting. Here, i've incremented in partition's for loop and also every time recQuickSort is called. What am I missing?

```
private void swap(T[] list, int first, int second)
{
     T temp;
     temp = list[first];
     list[first] = list[second];
     list[second] = temp;
     swapsNo++;
}


public void quickSort(T[] list, int length)
{
    recQuickSort(list, 0, length - 1);
}


private int partition(T[] list, int first, int last)
{
    T pivot;

    int smallIndex;

    swap(list, first, (first + last) / 2);

    pivot = list[first];
    smallIndex = first;


    for (int index = first + 1; index <= last; index++)
    {
        Comparable<T> compElem = (Comparable<T>) list[index];
        //Trying to increment comparisons for every time element compared to pivot
        compsNo++;
        if (compElem.compareTo(pivot) < 0)
        {
            smallIndex++;
            swap(list, smallIndex, index);

        }
    }

    swap(list, first, smallIndex);

    return smallIndex;
}



private void recQuickSort(T[] list, int first, int last)
{
    //Trying to increment comparisons every time, as first and last are compared
    compsNo++;
    if (first < last)
    {
        int pivotLocation = partition(list, first, last);
        recQuickSort(list, first, pivotLocation - 1);
        recQuickSort(list, pivotLocation + 1, last);

    }
}
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, my answer lies here in this similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646233/counting-quicksort-comparisons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first look of it i dont see where you would be counting extra comparisons. The easiest way to do these type of counting though is to create a CountingComparator class that increments on every compare.

```
class CountingComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Comparator<T> {

      private int count = 0;
      public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        ++count;
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
      }

      public int getCount() { return count; }
}
```

Also if your T would be bound to Comparable you coupd avoid the casts

Comment: okay, I'd originally tried to adapt a similar idea from this thread: stackoverflow.com/questions/8292615/… but, i'm a beginner in Java and had issues knowing how to call the compareInt method. What do you mean by 'if your T would be bound to Comparable you could avoid the casts'?

Comment: What I meant is that I assume that these functions are part of a generic class where the generic parameter is T, if like MyClass<T> but if your class were MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> then you wouldn't need to cast

Comment: I added an example that should help, though I couldn't test it ATM. It's also not thread safe, but that shouldn't concern you in this case